# Copy SQL Data from Backup Table to Other Table

Tags: sql, mariadb

What is the simplest way to copy the data from one MariaDB SQL table to another table that already has all of the same columns. Basically we have a backup table (`crdynamics.customer_records_backup`) with some sample data, and I want to copy that data into another table (`crdynamics.customer_records`). Again, these are identical tables - just one has data and one doesn't.

What's the simplest syntax available to accomplish that?

I tried this, but the syntax is incorrect:

```
UPDATE crdynamics.customer_records
SELECT *
FROM
    crdynamics.customer_records_backup
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to just want an `INSERT` rather than an `UPDATE`.

```
INSERT crdynamics.customer_records (<ColumnList>)
SELECT
 <ColumnList>
FROM 
 crdynamics.customer_records_backup;
```

Technically, you can do this:

```
INSERT crdynamics.customer_records 
SELECT
 *
FROM 
 crdynamics.customer_records_backup;
```

But always specifying column names is far less error-prone.

Comment: You type faster than me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use insert into select statement

```
insert into crdynamics.customer_records 
SELECT * FROM crdynamics.customer_records_backup 
where 1=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE new_backup LIKE real_table;
INSERT INTO new_backup SELECT * FROM real_table;
RENAME TABLE backup TO old_backup, new_backup TO backup;
DROP TABLE old_backup;
```

Notes:

- `backup` always exists and is populated, unlike cases that involve `TRUNCATE`, etc.
- By doing `CREATE .. LIKE` and `RENAME`, you grab the current schema, even if it has changed.
- The `RENAME` is atomic.
- (Drawback) During the process, there are 3 copies of the table; this could be a disk space issue.
- (Drawback) `INSERT .. SELECT`, `real_table` blocks some other activity.
- The answers that mention only `INSERT .. SELECT` fail to say what happens on the *second* backup.